# How to extend all views with my BasePresenter

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin, mvp

Im working on a project and doing mvp on it, now, I have a BaseActivity for all my Activities and a BasePresenter that works with the view of the Activity I'm in, this is done to attach, ditach and know wherever my view is null or not while working with my presenter.

Now, this is working fine for my first view with this

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : LoginContract.View> : Presenter<T> {

    private var mMvpView: T? = null

    val isViewAttached: Boolean
        get() = mMvpView != null

    override fun attachView(view: T) {
        mMvpView = view
    }

    override fun detachView() {
        mMvpView = null
    }
}
```

And in my presenter , I'm calling it like this

```
class LoginPresenter: BasePresenter<LoginContract.View>(), LoginContract.Presenter {

....
```

But now , I'm creating a new presenter that is called **RegisterPresenter** and when I use BasePresenter<> to extend my class with the presenter, it asks to put `LoginContract.View` in there.

I know that because is coded this way here

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : LoginContract.View> : Presenter<T> {
...
```

But I wonder if there is an approach where I can extend multiple views like this

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : multipleViews> : Presenter<T> {
```

Comment: Can't you make a Base View like you did with your BasePresenter and replace LoginContract.View with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend multiple classes. You should use some base interface instead.

#### How you can do this

1. Base presenter can use some `BaseView` interface:

```
abstract class BasePresenter<T : BaseView> : Presenter<T>
```

`LoginContract.View` interface should extend `BaseView`.
`RegisterContract.View` also should extend `BaseView`.

2. Then if you need one general presenter that works with all views you need to create general interface:

```
interface AllViews: LoginContract.View, RegisterContract.View
```

3. Now you can use it in GeneralPresenter

```
class GeneralPresenter : BasePresenter<AllView>
```